# Depth of field depreciated and canvases issue

Tags: shader, unity-game-engine

I've got a little problem with canvases when using depth of field depriciated on the main camera. How can I make it so that the depth of field does not apply to canvases whatsoever? As you can see in the screenshot, it blurs almost the entire canvas out. How can I fix this.
P.S. I've saw some solutions with the second camera added but I don't think that this would work in my UI menu level since the camera flies around the menu on button pressed, or maybe not, just giving a clear picture of the level idea.

I have the screenshot here:

The UI Menu Shot

[image]

Comment: What render mode are you using for your canvas?

Comment: You could use another camera for canvas UI ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add another camera which will render only the UI. Make it a child of the main camera.
   [image]
2. Set the Culling Mask of Main camera to ignore UI layer.
   [image]
3. Set the Culling Mask of UI Camera to render only the UI layer.
4. Set Clear Flags of UI Camera to Depth Only.
   [image]
5. Make sure to set the Render Camera of your canvas to the UI Camera

Comment: I can't see any canvases when I hit play

Comment: Oh I forgot, please make sure you set the Render Camera of your canvas to the UI Camera

Comment: So In each canvas I should set the UICamera as Event Camera, right?

Comment: Still can't see the vancas

Comment: Did you make sure your UI Cameras local position and rotation is set to zero? Can you please give a screenshot of your camera settings and canvas settings?

Comment: Maybe I've created the UICamera wrong as a child camera of the Main one? May I should assign it to be equal to the main camera position or something like that?

Comment: Can't send the screenshots, my score here is too low

Comment: Make sure the UICamera's Transform is like this screenshot:
http://imgur.com/5kZATXe
However, you can use imgur to share screenshot